# Как скрыть информацию о пк и сети при отправке Get запроса через python?

Tags: python, requests, get, безопасность, https

Мне нужно отправить полностью анонимный GET запрос через Python. Ниже условная часть кода

```
import requests
requests.get("Адрес")
```

Сейчас использую виртуальную машину(VMWare Workstation) с ОС Kali Linux, а так же VPN

Скрывает ли это информацию о моём пк(IP) и сетевую инф-цию?

Если нет/частично, так как полностью скрыть эти данные?

Comment: учитывая то, что вы отправляете запрос через VPN и с виртуальной машины, то в целом информация скрывается от посторонних глаз, кроме, конечно, спецслужб